# Not able to get the data from GET response

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rest

I am making a `GET` http request and getting a response like this

```
> {
>     "name": "mydata",
>     "hostname": "1.1.1.1",
>     "pid": 8,
>     "logger": "api.handlers.mylogger.",
>     "requestId": "0g79188d-0980-9867-65kk-78b580d1d922",
>     "level": 30,
>     "msg": "result is: {\"statusCode\":200,\"body\":\"Successfully queried the
> database.\",\"data\":{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"Test\",\"TimeStamp\":1590032892030,\"TimeStamp1\":1590032913860"}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":1}}",
>     "time": "2020-05-10T04:09:09.669Z",
>     "v": 0 }
```

I want the data that comes in `data` tag which is:

```
{\"Items\":[{\"Name\":\"Test\",\"TimeStamp\":1590032892030,\"TimeStamp1\":1590032913860"}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":1}}
```

I was trying to do like this:

```
var getResponse = MakeGetRequest();
var contents = getResponse.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

My `contents` is only showing the `Successfully queried the database`

```
var dataRootObject = JObject.Parse(contents).ToObject<Data1>();
```

The above line raises an exception.

```
public partial class Data1
    {
        [JsonProperty("Items")]
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Count")]
        public long Count { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ScannedCount")]
        public long ScannedCount { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Empty
    {
        [JsonProperty("statusCode")]
        public long StatusCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data1 Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar doesnt work

Comment: @Patrick Hofman Can you please have a look

Comment: The response you have posted seems to have issues with quotations. E.g. I think the quotation after the no. 1590032913860 is misplaced. Can you provide us with a clean response without the '>' etc? You can use 'Postman' to make your queries and get clean responses.

Answer (score 0):

First, your result is not correct.
May be the correct form is as below:

```
{"name":"mydata","hostname":"1.1.1.1","pid":8,"logger":"api.handlers.mylogger.","requestId":"0g79188d-0980-9867-65kk-78b580d1d922","level":30,"msg":"result is: {   \"statusCode\": 200,   \"body\": \"Successfully queried the database.\",   \"data\": {     \"Items\": [       {         \"Name\": \"Test\",         \"TimeStamp\": 1590032892030,         \"TimeStamp1\": 1590032913860       }     ],     \"Count\": 1,     \"ScannedCount\": 1   } }","time":"2020-05-10T04:09:09.669Z","v":0}
```

Then you need to convert it using below class structure:

```
var dataRootObject = JObject.Parse(contents).ToObject<RawData>();
```

Here is class structure:

```
public class RawData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string hostname { get; set; }
    public int pid { get; set; }
    public string logger { get; set; }
    public string requestId { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public int v { get; set; }
}
```

Once you get the **msg** string, you can get your data part string only and convert it to object below:

```
var yourData= JObject.Parse(dataRootObject.msg.Replace("result is: ","")).ToObject<Data1>();
```

Here is the class structure.

```
public class Data1
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int ScannedCount { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public long TimeStamp1 { get; set; }
}
```

That's it.
Good luck!

Comment: what is msgData, i cant figure it out

Comment: sorry it should be dataRootObject.msg. see my updated code.